# Media Source Api not working for a custom webm file (Chrome Version 23.0.1271.97 m)

Tags: javascript, html, video, streaming, media-source

I am referring a media source api demo given on this [link](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/media-source.html)

It is working fine for the given test webm file but when i tried to change the name of the file to a custom webm file the code stopped working.

It is generating following error : `Uncaught Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11` at following code :  `sourceBuffer.append(new Uint8Array(e.target.result));`

To check whether the custom webm file is working i have created a test page in which i have defined a video tag having source of that custom webm file.
When i ran the code it is working fine.

I am unable to understand the reason for this strange behavior.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The most likely problem is your WebM file has Clusters that don't start with a keyframe.

In Chrome dev-channel builds (ie Chrome 25 or later), you can verify this with the following steps.

1. Open chrome:media-internals in another tab.
2. Return to the tab with your test page and reload it.
3. When the error occurs again, switch back to chrome:media-internals tab and look for the bottom entry under the "Active media players:" header. It should have the same blob: URL that you passed to the video element src attribute.
4. Click on the blob: URL to expand the player data.
5. Click on the "Log:" entry to expose the player logging data.
6. Search for entries that have "MEDIA_SOURCE_ERROR" in the "Event:" column. These entries should provide information about what is wrong with the content passed to the browser.

If you see a message that says something like "Media segment did not begin with keyframe." then it means your file has Clusters that don't start with a keyframe. This is common with content that is generated by FFmpeg. You can fix your file in one of the following ways:

1. Run the sample_muxer program mentioned in section 2.2.5 of the [WebM adaptive streaming guide](https://sites.google.com/a/webmproject.org/wiki/adaptive-streaming/instructions-to-playback-a-webm-dash-presentation)
2. Run the mse_webm_remuxer program I wrote as part of my [mse-tools](http://github.com/acolwell/mse-tools) project.

Comment: thanks aaron for replying. i have followed the steps as mentioned by you and found out that the error was same as mentioned by you.

Comment: Now i am following the step 1 that is run the sample_muxer program. I have visited the link as mentioned by you. I have read the prerequisites in which it is mentioned that FFmpeg, libwebm and webm-tools are required. I have downloaded the windows builds of FFmpeg and added in the environment variable path and checked in the cmd. I have downloaded the libwebm folder but i dont know how to configure it and the third prerequisite webm-tools link there is nothing to download. Please help me to make it working.

Comment: After analyzing the code i found out that simple_muxer is a application built in cpp. I have installed the Dev-C++ software but when i try to compile the file sound_mixer.cpp i am getting errors

Comment: The second approach of running the mse_webm_remuxer progran has worked for me. Thanks aaron for your valuable suggestion.

Comment: You can prevent FFmpeg from creating clusters without keyframes if you set the cluster size limit high enough; I use "-cluster_size_limit 10M -cluster_time_limit 10K"

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: no internal error shown in my case (accepted answer suggests to check) but still the same problem**

I ran into the same trouble when trying to play recorded .webm file by **MediaRecorder API** back using **Media Source Extensions** (MSE). Chrome (51) recordings are malformed, Firefox (46) seems OK.

To get it working you have to fix cues in .webm file:

1. clone https://github.com/webmproject/libwebm
2. make sure you have cmake version >= 3.2 (https://askubuntu.com/questions/610291/how-to-install-cmake-3-2-on-ubuntu-14-04)
3. `cmake .`
4. `make`
5. `./sample_muxer -i original.webm -o fixed.webm`
6. load fixed.webm into DASH / your own player!

Hope it helped someone. It was quite difficult to google any information without the DASH keyword (i am not using DASH, only the same underlying technology - MSE) :)

Comment: I've been wrestling with this for awhile now. Are you aware of a way this can work in chrome? Maybe by fixing the webm in real time?

Comment: it should work in Chrome. It has been a while i wrote this but it was working in Chrome, Firefox and Opera.

Comment: Hey sorry, I meant is there a way to record using the MediaRecorder API that will immediately playable in Chrome. Without the need to remux the video.

Comment: It was not possible in Chrome 51. Maybe it is working now, i have not tried it. However if you do not need recording, you do not have to use MediaRecorderAPI (for example if you just want to show/stream MediaStream).