# Mediasource API Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not

Tags: html, media-source

Media source API is working fine when I downloaded all files from https://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/media-source.html . However, when I replaced the name of file in line 137, chrome dev tools  gave
`Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable`

I have made no other change to the file and uploaded it on dropbox.
@line 137
`
- var FILE = 'test.webm';
+ var FILE = 'b8756219.webm';

Chrome Version 31.0.1650.63
Ubuntu 13.10
Both are webm files but one of them is giving errors. What am I missing?
`

Comment: The error you're getting is from trying to append a chunk to a closed source buffer.  `mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceclose', function(e) {console.log("SOURCE CLOSED");}, false);` will let you know when this happens.  The question is why was it closed early? Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14048349/2601193) to get a better error message.  It's likely something wrong with your .webm file.  Media-source is less forgiving of incorrect timestamp offsets and such in a video file.

Comment: @AdamHart Thanks, I followed the instruction in the link you gave and found the error: "Media segment did not begin with keyframe"

Comment: You can *try* using this [mse webm remuxer](https://github.com/acolwell/mse-tools) to fix the video, though I've had mixed results on sample .webm files I've used.